# Slicing a string based on common delimeter in Python

Tags: python, string, slice

I'd like to take the following string and slice it based on the pipe delimeter:

```
address = '1234 Broadway Ave | Los Angeles | CA | 94530'
```

I figured out the first piece:

```
street = address[:address.index('|')]
print(street)
1234 Broadway Ave
```

But I am unclear on how to get city/state/zip:

```
city = 
state = 
zip =
```

Also, is there a better way to do this?  Using RegEx or something similar?  Haven't used that before..

Thanks!

Comment: If you are trying to parse csv data with a different delimeter, [batteries are included](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get each item by just splitting on `'|'` with [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), and using [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to take away the leading and trailing whitespace of each item:

```
address = '1234 Broadway Ave | Los Angeles | CA | 94530'

items = [x.strip() for x in address.split('|')]

print(items)
```

Which gives:

```
['1234 Broadway Ave', 'Los Angeles', 'CA', '94530']
```

Additionally, you can also do this nicely with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map):

```
items = list(map(str.strip, address.split('|')))
```

You could also assign these items to a dictionary using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), like so:

```
contents = ["street", "city", "state", "zip"]
d = dict(zip(contents, items))
print(d)
```

Which would give you this structure:

```
{'street': '1234 Broadway Ave', 'city': 'Los Angeles', 'state': 'CA', 'zip': '94530'}
```

Then you could access each item in this dictionary by simply calling the keys:

```
>>> d['street']
1234 Broadway Ave
>>> d['city']
Los Angeles
>>> d['state']
CA
>>> d['zip']
94530
```